# Finding number of possible hands in 5 card stud when order is matter

Tags: probability, permutations, poker

I'm trying to determine the game 5 card poker when order is matter all my trails ended with fail except the one pair. 
The way I did one pair assuming it is $\{k,k,x,y,z\}$

$^{13}P_1 \times ^4P_2 \times ^{12}P_3 \times (^4P_3)^3$

Taking 1 permutation out of 13 cards and then multiply it with how many suit permutation for the first 2. in this case we will have the possible hands of the first two cards with order. Then by multiply it with the second part of taking 3 different cards from the rest (12 cards) including the 4 different suits I got the right number.  13,178,880

Now by applying the same rule to Two-pair $\{kk,dd,x\}$ using two different ways.

1- $^{13}P_1 \times ^4P_2 \times ^{12}P_1 \times ^4P_2 \times ^{11}P_1 \times ^4P_1 =  988,416$

2- $^{13}P_2 \times(^4P_2)^2 \times ^{11}P_1 \times ^4P_1 = 988,416$

the result is wrong. Considering the permutation between the three group which means multiply the result by $^3P_3$ = 6 is equal to 5,930,496 is still wrong the correct result based on the book is 14,826,240.

My trials stopped just here waiting to find a way and the two find the answer for the rest of the game.

Comment: Sorry, the book says there are more ways to get two pair then there are to get one pair?  That seems wrong.

Comment: As a (minor) variant on your method, I would count your particular two pair $AABBC$ as $52\times 3\times 48 \times 3  \times 44=988,416$.  (no condition on first card, second can then only be one of three, third can be anything of different rank, fourth is one of three, fifth must have a new rank).  Same answer you got.

Comment: the question is talking about order so it might change the answer if we consider  AABBC, BBAAC, BBCA, ......

Comment: There are $\frac {5!}{2!\;2!}=30$ ways to permute $AABBC$ .  Of course switching $A$ and $B$ does not give us a new configuration, so we need only consider $15$ of these.  Thus your final answer is $15*988416=14,826,240$ (as the book reports).  I am still very surprised that this is greater than the number of single pair hands...but I haven't checked that calculation.

Comment: Oh, Ok.  I misread your calculation.  For single pair hands:  Starting with the pattern $AABCD$ we have $52\times 3\times 48 \times 44 \times 40=13,178,880$   But that's just one pattern.  I thought you were saying that was the final answer.  There are $\binom 52 = 10$ possible patterns (according to where the $AA$ goes) so the total number is ten times that.  That makes more sense.

Comment: regarding you first comment, how did you arrive to this answer 30 and 15, If I'll see it as 3 sub groups and to do permutation between them I'll have 3P3 which is 6.

Comment: for the second comment exactly it was one pattern, but again how did u define it is 10 patterns.

Comment: Start with permutations of $XYZWV$.  There are $5!$ of these.  Now, we are told that $X=Y$ so we must divide by $2$ (As switching $X,Y$ has no effect).  Likewise we must divide by $2$ again, as switching $Z,W$ has no effect.  Thus we get $\frac {5!}4=30$ ways to permute $AABBC$.  Now we have an additional symmetry of your situation in that $BBAAC$ is the same as $AABBC$.  That is, switching $A,B$ has no effect.  Thus we get an additional factor of $2$, hence $15$.

Comment: Similarly, for the single pair case all you need to do is to place the pair $AA$.  There are $\binom 52=10$ ways to do that.  As an alternate argument note that, a priori, there are $5$ ways to place the first $A$, then $4$ to place the second.  That gives $5\times 4=20$ but we have to divide by two to account for the equality between the two $A's$.

Comment: excuse me for going into details. 15 permutation taking into account switching between A's or B's or AA and BB has no different. means we should end up with these possibilities only.  AABBC, AACBB, CAABB. 3  permutation. where are the rest of the 15. I might be not understanding it very well.

Comment: What about $ACABB$?

Comment: If you want a different argument:  there are $5$ ways to place the $C$.  Then there are $3$ ways to put two pair in $4$ slots:  $AABB,\;ABAB,\;ABBA$.

Comment: I discovered this result based on your last answer which leads me to ask why did you exclude the symmetry situation from the result?

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow your last comment.  I am giving you multiple arguments  to get the number $15$.  The permutation arguments start with large collections that have to be cut down (via symmetry).  The most recent just builds the list up from scratch.  In general, I prefer the symmetry arguments (because they're all you have when the numbers get large) but the constructive method is great when it works.

Comment: it is my mistake I should have said the symmetry $AABB$ = $BBAA$

Comment: Here...I'll list all $15$ for you:  $CAABB,ACABB,AACBB,AABCB,AABBC,CABAB,ACBAB,ABCAB,ABACB,ABABC,CABBA,ACBBA,ABCBA, ABBCA,ABBAC$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation that got you 988416 is correct. However, there should be $\displaystyle \frac{5!}{2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2!}$ possible permutations for $\{kk,dd,x\}$.

$5!$ is the number of permutations for 5 cards, and the three $2!$'s in the denominator represents the numbers of permutations of the 2 $k$'s, the 2 $d$'s, as well as $kk$ and $dd$.

$$ 988416 \times \frac{5!}{2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2!} = 14826240 $$

Comment: Now I got it, you applied the order partitions rule on the result to get the possible permutation from the main possible results. but the last factorial $2!$ shouldn't be $1!$